# Jenkins Pipeline checkout branch which can parameterised

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write a stage in Jenkinsfile where I'll pass the branch name from the Jenkins job to checkout the code at a specific location.

```
stage("Prepare") {
        steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                        branches: [[name: '*/master' ]],
                        extensions: scm.extensions,
                        userRemoteConfigs: [[
                            url: 'https://gitlab.example.com/user/example_repo.git',
                            credentialsId: 'my-gitlab-repo-creds'
                        ]]
                    ])
        }
    }
```

Also, how can we define the location where to checkout the project.

Comment: Needing to clone a second project to a different location and trying to parameterize the BRANCH_NAME are two separate things.  What's the end goal?

Comment: parameterize branch_name

Comment: simply wrap in into a dir('directory-name'){ ... } block?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the power of the [SCM checkout step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/).  In turn, your pipeline is missing some important configuration to get what you want:

1. pass the branch name from the Jenkins job to checkout the code
2. define the location where to checkout the project

This can all be done.  I'll explain the options used to accomplish this.

**1) Pass the branch name to checkout step**

You can achieve this with the `BRANCH_NAME` [environment variable](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables).

**2) Define project checkout location**

Add the following extension and get rid of the `scm.extensions` value.

```
extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'myrepo']]
```

> Specify a local directory (relative to the workspace root) where the Git repository will be checked out. If left empty, the workspace root itself will be used.

For the `branches` option,

> The safest way is to use the refs/heads/ syntax. This way the expected branch is unambiguous.

For example:

```
branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/${env.BRANCH_NAME}']]
```

Piecing it all together,

```
checkout(
  [
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'example_repo']],
    branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/${env.BRANCH_NAME}']],
    userRemoteConfigs: [
      [
        url: 'https://gitlab.example.com/user/example_repo.git',
        credentialsId: 'my-gitlab-repo-creds',
        name: 'origin'
      ]
    ]
  ]
)
```

The above code will checkout the `${env.BRANCH_NAME}` branch of `https://gitlab.example.com/user/example_repo.git` to the `$WORKSPACE_DIR/example_repo` folder.