# GitHub checkout with environmental variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, git-checkout

In Jenkins, I have a multibranch pipeline job using a Jenkinsfile.  I have disabled the default SCM checkout via:

```
options {skipDefaultCheckout(true)}
```

so that I can control the checkout for each stage and use the SSH URL from GitHub.  I have a working stage that checks out the "main" branch using:

```
   checkout([
       $class: 'GitSCM', 
       branches: [[name: '*/main']], 
       extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: 'main']], 
       userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'XXX', url: 'git@github.com:XXX.git']]
    ])
```

For another stage, I would like to checkout and build/test the branch that is triggered (in this case a feature branch called "feature-0001").  I have tried this (note the change for the branches and extensions lines):

```
 checkout([
       $class: 'GitSCM', 
       branches: [[name: env.BRANCH_NAME]], 
       extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch']], 
       userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: XXX, url: 'git@github.com:XXX.git']]
    ])
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error when executing failure post condition:

java.io.IOException: Cannot retrieve Git metadata for the build
```

In addition, the build log also has:

```
git rev-parse "origin/feature-0001^{commit}" # timeout=10

git rev-parse "feature-0001^{commit}" # timeout=10
```

I'm not sure where the "^{commit}" comes from or if it's causing any issues.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you!

P.S. I have also tried many variations of BRANCH_NAME including

```
$env.BRANCH_NAME, ${env.BRANCH_NAME}, $BRANCH_NAME, ${BRANCH_NAME}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an unambiguous way to reference your branch name in the [SCM `checkout` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-check-out-from-version-control), try (as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63890768/6309)):

```
branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/${env.BRANCH_NAME}']]
```

The [`^{commit}` revision specification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrevgtlttypegtemegemv0998commitem) would therefore apply to the ref `refs/heads/${env.BRANCH_NAME}`

> ### `<rev>^{<type>}`, e.g. `v0.99.8^{commit}`
>
> A suffix `^` followed by an object type name enclosed in brace pair means **dereference** the object at `<rev>` recursively until an object of type `<type>` is found or the object cannot be dereferenced anymore (in which case, barf).
>
> For example, if `<rev>` is a commit-ish, `<rev>^{commit}` describes the corresponding commit object.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I tried changing the branches line as you suggest and I still get the same error.  No change except it now says :

git rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/${env.BRANCH_NAME}^{commit}" # timeout=10

Comment: @tsteinbaugh-beckman Is it possible to display `${env.BRANCH_NAME}` value (in place of the checkout step)?

Comment: Apologies, I was using single quotes rather than double quotes, so the ${env.BRANCH_NAME} was not being recognized.  I still have the same overall failure, but git rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/${env.BRANCH_NAME}^{commit} is now back to git rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/feature-0001^{commit}" # timeout=10

Comment: echo ${env.BRANCH_NAME} gives the expected result of feature-0001.

Answer (score 1):

`branches: [[name: "refs/heads/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"]]` worked.

I was also using the incorrect url/credentials causing further issues.